# LaTeX - tabularx and image side-by-side with minipage

Tags: align, tabularx, minipage

I've already searched the forum for solutions but none of them seem to work for me. What I am trying to accomplish is to build a table on the left side and put an image to its right - they BOTH shall start at the TOP.

I am using the `[t]`-operator already, but it still not works. Anyone got an idea?

Here is my source code:

```
\newpage
\section{xxxxxx}
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 

    % Person_1
\vspace{7pt}
\subsection{xxxxxx}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{7pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx   \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx   \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

But this is the output:
[image: The output]

I'd like the picture to start in the same horizontal line as the first table-entry next to the green line. No matter how big or small the picture is, they both shall start at the top. How can I achieve this?

In case you have a solution without minipage, feel free to show me. The code is not interesting for me, but the output in the pdf.

Kind regards,
Krypton :)

Comment: Welcome, please have a look at [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and 
[minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to see how to provide a minimal working example for us to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick hack: add zero vertical spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{xxxxxx}
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 

    % Person_1
\vspace{7pt}
\subsection{xxxxxx}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.68\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}%
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{7pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx  \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx   \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx   \\
        \textit{x} & xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx  
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.28\textwidth}
                \vspace{0pt}%
        \rule{3cm}{3cm}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! :D May I ask what {-\baselineskip} does?

Comment: @Krypton It shifts the table upwards by one line (as I said, just a quick hack :)